# Bazel: Compile a single file without linking

Tags: c++, bazel

**Question**

In `ninja`, I can compile a single C++ file by running `ninja path/to/my/object.file.o`.

Is there a way to achieve the same in bazel?

**Use case / Background**

During refactoring, in particular when changing interfaces in `.hpp` files, I usually want to focus on one single complex user of the interface first. I want to iterate on that one user until my refactoring works as expected on `complex_user.cpp` and I am happy with the new interfaces. Only afterwards, I want to adjust all other users. I hence want to get the compiler errors / warnings *only* from my `complex_user.cpp` file while ignoring all other places where `.hpp` might be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [--save_temps](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--save_temps). `bazel build --save_temps //my:library` will give you the `.o`, `.s`, and similar files for only the targets listed on the command line.

[--compile_one_dependency](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--compile_one_dependency) is designed for a similar use case, if you want to specify the target to build by the `.cpp` file instead of specifying a particular `cc_library`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a custom-made rule `cc_object_file`. Since the Bazel  `cc_rules` are open source you can use this as a starting point.